# How to get email recipients from new order email in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, methods, woocommerce, email-notifications

I would like to get the recipients field value from WooCommerce emails settings for "New Order" email as shown below:

[image]

How to get Recipient(s) field? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using the following simple line:

```
WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_New_Order']->recipient;
// Or: WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_New_Order']->get_recipient();
// Or: WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_New_Order']->settings['recipient'];
```

Or in details (code is commented):

```
// Get an instance of the WC_emails Object 
$wc_emails = WC()->mailer();

// Get available emails notifications
$emails_array = $wc_emails->get_emails();

// Get the instance of the WC_Email_New_Order Object
$new_order_email = $emails_array['WC_Email_New_Order'];

// Get recipients from New Order email notification
$new_order_recipient = $new_order_email->recipient;
// Or $new_order_email->get_recipient(); 
// Or $new_order_email->settings['recipient'];
```

> The Class [`WC_Email_New_Order`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Email_New_Order.html) is *"An email **sent to the admin** when a new order is received / paid for"* *(as you can see on the docs)*.
>
> The `WC_Email` method [`get_recipient()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Email.html#_get_recipient) use in it's source code `$this->recipient` where `$this` is the `WC_Email_New_Order` Object in this case *(as it extends the [`WC_Email` Class](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Email.html))*.
>
> You can use either the method `get_recipient()`, the property `recipient` or `settings['recipient']`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 
But if i use $new_order_email->get_recipient(); this will return email billing for customer, 
So i change is $new_order_email->recipient; this right

Comment: @TanKyBui It's the same thing normally as "New Order" notification is set in WooCommerce settings to be sent to an admin  recipient(s). Anyways I have updated my code to reflect your comment. you can also use: `$new_order_email->settings['recipient'];`